# Screenshots from a Mac with Retina display

Tags: discussion

Ever since I got my new [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro), the screen shots I post on Stack Overflow are doubled in size. Here's a sample from this very screen (taken on a [Retina screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display)):

[image]

Now compare this to the same screen shot taken on my old MacBook Pro:

[image]

Apparently, it's only half the size.

Any idea how to get around this? I could down-scale those screenshots each time, but that somehow makes me feel like being on the wrong party (hey, I paid six times more for this machine than for my first motor bike 40 years ago and now I have to do *that*?). I'd feel better if I could tell on upload that this is double the *normal* resolution. There isn't any meta-flag in the PNG image that could be detected, I guess?

Comment: Welcome to my life. I write a lot of Confluence documentation and need to feed every image into preview and scale them down by either 25% or 50% to make the images usable. Of course you can configure confluence to scale them, but imaging tools tend to have a little better algorithms for it than a browser does and it saves on disc space. It's just the way it is.

Comment: @Gimby That's what's called "progress" :-/